# How to export a point cloud?

Tags: python, point-clouds, 3d-modelling

So I'm working on a 3D scanner, and I made some 3D reconstruction code.
Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/VidOsep/51deb22b29037b48cb14f273c1dbbd06).
But because I'm more of a noob, I'm not sure how I could export the point cloud, and afterwards use it a 3d modelling program, like blender.

Comment: have a look [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)

Comment: I know how to write to a file, just I don't know how I could open that file in something like blender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import [PLY format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/) and [OBJ format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/) into Blender both support ASCII files. Write out the appropriate ASCII file with the appropriate headers & as long as you have the format correct they should be readable by programs that support PLY & OBJ.

Alternatively you could use [Python's CSV library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) save your data as a CSV file and import into Blender as a CSV using Blenders Python API.

Answer (score 9):

I cant be sure without having a example of the result of the 3D reconstruction, but based on the code you linked to I think that you could generate a .ply file ready to be imported to Blender as follows:

Using https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from pyntcloud import PyntCloud

cloud = PyntCloud(pd.DataFrame(
    # same arguments that you are passing to visualize_pcl
    data=np.hstack((points, colors)),
    columns=["x", "y", "z", "red", "green", "blue"]))

cloud.to_file("output.ply")
```

Answer (score 2):

As David de la Iglesia said, you can use the https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud package. But the way he did it the color doesn't work because it's in the float format, due to stacking it together with the coordinates.

```
d = {'x': points[:,0],'y': points[:,1],'z': points[:,2], 
             'red' : colors[:,0], 'green' : colors[:,1], 'blue' : colors[:,2]}
        
cloud = PyntCloud(pd.DataFrame(data=d))
cloud.to_file("output.ply")
```

The matrix "points" is in float format and "colors" in uint8